# How change default value drop folder in Release Management

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

I'm configuring Release Management 2013, I search issue:
My TFS create drop folder like this:  \ServerName\DropFolder\Project\Project_20141230.1
But when I start release in Release Management, It try search in this drop folder: \ServerName\DropFolder\Project\Project20141230.1

So, where can I change template of drop folder in release management?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've connected your release template to a build definition, the drop folder is queried from the build that you're releasing. If you've moved or deleted the binaries since the build was completed, RM won't be able to find them. I suspect that's what happened here.